# Formula field based on status

Tags: formula, validation

If Status equals Completed and if field is blank, what would the formula look like?

Having issues with the formula

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Can you please post the formula which is causing the issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you ask "what would the formula look like?" Are you asking about how to take your given statement, and turn it into a formula? Please go into more detail about the issues that you're encountering. If you're seeing an error, please [edit] your question to include the error message **verbatim**. Generally speaking, the more details you give, the better your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, there is a [formula field unit on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/formula_fields) which should help you get started if you're new to Salesforce (or formula fields).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a formula field or a validation rule? A formula generally returns data but you don't explain what data you're looking for. A validation rule will stop the execution of a save and only returns a true/false value. Your question seems to imply validation rule is what you need.

**Validation Rule:**

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(status, 'Completed'), ISBLANK(Description))
```

This is a validation rule that will stop you from closing a case without a description. Simply change your description field to the field you need.

**Formula Field:**

There's not many differences between the two:

```
IF( AND(ISPICKVAL(status, 'Completed'), ISBLANK(Description)), 'Missing Data', 'Data Complete' )
```

This is basically the same thing except it will populate a field with either "Missing Dat" or "Data Complete" depending on whether or not the description is populated.

Chances are, what is causing your confusion is that you're not using ISPICKVAL(field, 'String Literal') when comparing status. This function is generally required for formulas involving picklists and you will get errors if you try something like:

```
AND(Status = Completed, ISBLANK(Description))
```

Hope that helps.

**Addendum:**

Formulas can also be found in workflows and process builder processes, for these instances you'll want to use the same logic as the validation rule.

**Update Based on Comment:**

Formula provided by poster:

```
IF (Status__c (status, 'In Progress'), ISBLANK(START Start_Date__c )
```

This formula has a few flaws:

- Not using ISPICKVAL(Field, 'text literal')
- If Statement with no return values

**Corrected Formula:**

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'In Progress', ISBLANK(Start_Date__c), Value If True, Value if false)
```

Again, this formula looks like it's meant to be a validation rule. The correct Validation rule would be:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'In Progress'), ISBLANK(Start_Date__c))
```

**Another update**

Re-reading through this makes me think that "Start_Date__c" might be the field that you want updated when the status changes to in progress. In this instance a Formula field will not work. If you want the field to update automatically, you'll need to [create a workflow to handle the change](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005475&type=1).

Comment: IF (Status__c (status, 'In Progress'), ISBLANK(START Start_Date__c )

Comment: @Vanessa Updated my answer